# Get column by finding value in the row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I've looked into `hlookup`, `vlookup`, `match` and `index` but none of these functions do following:

I need to find a text value in `A1:Z1` and get the column of it. For example, I found the value in `F1`, then I want a result `F:F`.

EDIT: This is the function I want it to be added to:

```
=COUNTIFS(Source!B:B;Result!C3;Source!AT:AT;Result!$D$2)
```

I need the `Source!B:B` and alternatively `Source!AT:AT` be a search function that looks for a specific value in my table row and column in different sheet (Source).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

INDEX function can return a whole column, e.g. assuming you want to search for "x" in A1:Z1 try

`=INDEX(A:Z;0;MATCH("x";A1:Z1;0))`

Note: this doesn't return a text string like F:F, it returns a reference to the column in question which you would normally use within a function that  expects a whole column reference, e.g. SUM, SUMIF, LOOKUP etc.

Edited: You can use the above in COUNTIFS function like this:

`=COUNTIFS(INDEX(Source!A:Z;0;MATCH("x";Source!A1:Z1;0));Result!C3;Source!AT:AT;Result!$D$2)`

That makes the first range dynamic (between columns A and Z - extend as required) based on where "x" is first found in Source!A1:Z1, e.g. if "x" is first found in J1 then COUNTIFS uses Source!J:J for the first range - you can do that for any of the ranges in COUNTIFS

Comment: A:Z is the whole range from column A to column Z including all rows - I edited my answer to show how you can use INDEX within COUNTIFS to make the range dynamic dependant on finding a specific value in the header row

Comment: @Skuta As usual I am making this more complicated than it needs to be :) Barry's answer is much better, so work with this instead (and +1 to Barry :) )

Answer (score 2):

You can use this (it will return `E:E`, which you could then use `INDIRECT` with to return a workable range). This uses "words" as the word to match and stop at the first match:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(
    ADDRESS(1,MATCH("words",$A$1:$Z$1,0),4),"1",
    ":"&
    SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("words",$A$1:$Z$1,0),4),"1",""))
```

[image]

This works by using `MATCH` to find the position of the occurrence in your range (in this case, 5), and then using `ADDRESS`, with `row_num` = 1 and `column_num` = the result of the match. Using `4` for the `abs_num` argument ensures that the returned value will be without the `$`'s. You then substitute out the `1` in `E1` with ":" and concatenate it with the same formula, giving you `E:E` as a string. You can then do look-ups based on that range (using `INDIRECT`), such as this:

[image]

Comment: however even if i changed the functions to local names, the part of 1,MATCH is highlighted as something's wrong with it.

Comment: @Skuta Ha, well let's figure this out. I've noticed that sometimes copying a formula from SO changes some commas to semicolons when pasting - are there any semicolons in the formula after you paste?