# Array formula to return contents of adjacent cells based on multiple criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I need a formula that will firstly determine which column of a table to search in, based on the contents of a specified cell matched to a column header on the table. So let's say the cell with the required word is on Tab 1, in cell A1 and contains the word Task. The formula needs to search the column headers which are in Row 1 on Tab 2 to locate the column which has the header Task.

It then needs to search down that column to locate the words mandatory, which will appear multiple times, and return the contents of the adjacent cells in column B.

I have reviewed the array formulas on the following website:

http://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/03/28/search-for-a-text-string-and-return-multiple-adjacent-values/

The below formula gets me part of the way there but it does not fulfil my initial requirement as it fixed and is searching column A for my search term.

```
{INDEX($B$1:$B$5,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1,$A$1:$A$5)),MATCH(ROW($A$1:$A$5),ROW($A$1:$A$5))),ROW(A1)))}
```

I've also reviewed this page [Get column by finding value in the row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112877/get-column-by-finding-value-in-the-row). Barry's INDEX Formula seems to be what I'm after but I'm having trouble integrating the two formulas together.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: so if there are multiple hits for the word `mandatory` in your column labelled `task` you want to return each hit's adjacent cell? Like in a comma delimited list?

Comment: Potentially a poor use of the word adjacent by me. If the column labeled task is column F, and mandatory is found in cell F2, F5, etc, I want to return the value of cell B2, B5 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `B1` of `Sheet1`:

`=COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$1048576,,MATCH(A$1,Sheet2!$1:$1,0)),"mandatory")`

In `C1` of `Sheet1`, **array formula****:

`=IF(ROWS($1:1)>B$1,"",INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,SMALL(IF(INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$100,,MATCH(A$1,Sheet2!$1:$1,0))="mandatory",ROW(Sheet2!A$2:A$100)-MIN(ROW(Sheet2!A$2:A$100))+1),ROWS($1:1))))`

Copy the formula in `C1` down (though not that in `B1`, which is used to simply count the expected number of returns) until you start to get blanks for the results.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/812727/look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-all-multiple-corresponding-values) for an explanation as to why it is preferable to reference an additional counting cell (`B1`) rather than resort to `IFERROR` in such constructions

*Edit: the key construction here is the part*:

`INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$100,,MATCH(A$1,Sheet2!$1:$1,0))`

which takes advantage of the fact that if either (or both) of the row or column parameters passed to `INDEX` is zero (or, equivalently, omitted) and the `INDEX` is properly coerced (e.g. forms part of a larger formula), a reference to the entire specified column or row is generated.

Hence, and assuming that the value in `A1` occurs in `column D` of `Sheet2`, the above will resolve to:

`INDEX(Sheet2!$1:$100,,4)`

which is

`Sheet2!$D1:$D100`

See [here](https://excelxor.com/2014/08/18/index-returning-entire-rowscolumns/) for more on this property of `INDEX`.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Hi - I love this solution. Would you mind providing a tiny bit of explanation around the mechanics of the function for my learning?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain that you'll be able to do what you want with merely an array formula. Although, there are folks haunting SO that are better at Array formulas than me.

If you don't mind going the UDF route, you can use this UDF by sticking it in a new module in your workbook:

```
Function getList(headerValue As String, rowValue As String, lookupRange As Range, returnOffset As Integer) As String
    Dim lookupCol As Range, lookupCell As Range
    Dim getListOut As String

    'find the column to lookup into
    For Each lookupCol In lookupRange.Columns
        If lookupCol.Cells(1, 1).Value = headerValue Then Exit For
    Next lookupCol

    'search each cell in the column (for the lookupRange) for matchValue
    For Each lookupCell In Intersect(lookupCol, lookupRange).Cells

        'See if we have a match
        If lookupCell.Value = rowValue Then

            'Concatenate if necessary to the output
            If getListOut = "" Then
                getListOut = lookupCell.Offset(, returnOffset).Value
            Else
                getListOut = getListOut & "," & lookupCell.Offset(, returnOffset).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next lookupCell

    'return
    getList = getListOut
End Function
```

And using it in your cell (like B1 on your first tab "sheet1"):

```
=getList(A1,"mandatory", Sheet2!A1:G6, -3)
```

Here `A1` is the header value to search for, `"mandatory"` is the cell value to find in that header's column, `Sheet2!A1:G6` is the table to search in, and `-4` is the column offset to get the value from whatever row we found with `"mandatory" in it.

I put the word "task" in A1 and in the header (column F) on Sheet2 for that table. I put the three rows with the word "mandatory" and in Column B I put "d", "e", and "f" for each `mandatory`. This returned `d,e,f` as expected.

It's kind of like a hlookup in a vlookup that returns multiple hits in a comma delimited list, that also allows a negative offset.